# Trouble with lme() warning. In lme.formula( fewer observations than random effects in all level 2 groups

Tags: r

When I try to put random effects into my MLM model I get a warning message that says "fewer observations than random effects in all level 2 group". I can get random intercepts to work, but not random slopes. Is this because my data doesnt warrant that? (I am new to MLM and cant tell if I am doing something super wrong or if I specifying it incorrectly). Sometimes it even causes my R session to crash depending on what I have fiddled around with.

```r
#this is an example of a single participant (I have ~200)
> filter(a3, P.id == 76132)
# A tibble: 16 x 5
   species   P.id correct attractiveness aversiveness
   <ord>    <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 cat      75948   0.873           3.07        2.94 
 2 dog      75948   1               4.07        4.94 
 3 elephant 75948   1               3.07        1.94 
 4 horse    75948   1               3.07        2.94 
 5 cow      75948   0.873           2.07        3.94 
 6 duck     75948   0.873           1.07        1.94 
 7 hamster  75948   0.539           1.07        4.94 
 8 rabbit   75948   0.873           1.07        4.94 
 9 bear     75948   0.539           5.07        2.94 
10 leopard  75948   0.539           5.07        1.94 
11 tiger    75948   1               5.07        1.94 
12 lion     75948   1               5.07        1.94 
13 chicken  75948   0.873           1.07        1.94 
14 hippo    75948   1               2.07        0.940
15 lizzard  75948   0.873           2.07        0.940
16 snake    75948   0.873           4.07        0.940

# species is the species of the target for ratings
# P.id is the participant id
# correct is the proportion of correct responses (across 3 trials
# for each species)
# attractiveness is the attractiveness rating provided 1 time for a
# given species 
# aversiveness is the aversiveness rating provided 1 time for a
# given species 

mod.random.int <- lme(correct ~ aversiveness + attractiveness, a3,
                      random = ~ 1|P.id/species,
                      na.action = "na.omit",
                      control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 100),
                      method = "ML")

#this works

mod.random.int <- lme(correct ~ aversiveness + attractiveness, a3,
                      random = ~ aversiveness + attractiveness|P.id/species,
                      na.action = "na.omit",
                      control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 100),
                      method = "ML")

#this does not work (doesn't even complete running until I force it to stop) and I get the "fewer observations than random effects in 
#all level 2 group"
```

Can anybody shed some light on whats going on?

Comment: You likely don't have enough data points for each level of ID and species, so you may need to simplify your model.

Comment: Thanks @kstew. Thats what I was hoping is the case (I dont actually "want" the random slopes but wanted to make sure I didnt "need" them). Do you have a place I can go that explains why this is the case/a rule for understanding how many observations I need since I am trying to develop a full understanding of the dos and donts of MLM.

Comment: You can see in your example that there is no variation in attractiveness ratings for this ID across different species. I am not sure why `lme()` won't simply throw an error in your case. [This older tutorial](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf) may be worth checking out (it uses `lme4::lmer()` though, not `nlme`). It's always a good idea to plot your data beforehand to determine if a random slope/intercept is even worth including in your model. Good luck!

Comment: @kstew, sorry, in my haste I managed to select a very lazy participant who had atypical data. I edited it to show a different participant. Does this change anything?